# Ideas to clear user xattrs from files without get/setfattr

Tags: linux, filesystems, xattr, squashfs

I have a directory containing a root filesystem that I SquashFS and then mount as r/o on other boxes.

However, before SquashFS'ing, i want to clear all the user-namespace xattrs from the filesystem. This is trivial to do with a small `getfattr` and `setfattr` loop script, but I want to avoid introducing those as a dependency.

The sticky part is that I only want to clear the user xattrs. I need to preserve the security xattrs as they contain my SELinux labels. So simply telling Squash to not collect the xattrs is not an option.

One idea i had was to get the size of the filesystem, allocate a blank file of that size, format it as ext4, and mount it with `-o nouser_xattrr`, copy the files there, and then Squash them. This would work, but it's cumbersome, and i have to hope that I have enough space for the file. A tmpfs won't work because no xattr support, plus i may run out of memory.

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GNU tar can read xattrs and do filtering on them, see https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/Extended-File-Attributes.html.

A Squashfs filesystem can now be created from a tar archive using `sqfstar` (in version 4.5 and later).

So something like

```
tar --xattrs --xattrs-exclude='user.*' -c your-directory | sqfstar img.sqfs
```

Should work.

Comment: So 4.5 is fairly recent for where I'm going to be running this, but I can definitely use it for that purpose if that version is available. My main issue is that when unpacking a SquashFS to a tmpfs, it stops copying xattrs (which includes SELinux labels) as soon as it encounters a user xattr that can't be written. ignore_xattrs gets set and it's game over from there on. A flag that stops this behavior would be really nice, because there doesn't seem to be any way to work around this behavior except to prevent xattrs from getting in in the first place.

Comment: I'm going to end up using a variation of this solution, just using tar to strip the user xattrs in the case that my squashfs doesn't support this feature.
tar --recursion --selinux -c / | tar -x
Read the files, strip the xattrs, and just immediately write them back.